# FPD Link III Layout Best Practice

Tags: pcb-design, layout, digital-communications

I've been doing a lot of reading around FPD-Link III interfaces as I want to attempt to make my own vehicle camera system using a  DS90UB960-Q1 deserialiser and a DS90UB953-Q1 serialiser, but I've hit a bit of a wall when trying to optimise the PCB layout for the speeds in question.

Key information:

- I'm going to use a PoC configuration, ideally four channels for future development, each routed in a 50R microstrip configuration
- I will be using the same PoC components as recommended by TI on their deserialiser evaluation module (DS90UB960-Q1EVM)

According to the DS90UB960-Q1 deserialiser datasheet, Section 8.5.5.1 (page 177) states that a ground reference plane should be provided for the device, which makes sense if this is on the layer directly underneath the signal layer.

Looking at Figure 8-21 and reviewing the DS90UB960-Q1EVM, Texas Instruments have flooded their top and bottom signal layers with a polygon pour connected to ground, making their topology co-planar waveguide rather than microstrip.

My question is why? Is it better to do this? I understand that from a crosstalk perspective, adding a polygon pour to the signal layer may add slight benefit assuming shielding vias are used and configured correctly (in both spacing and diameter), but generally it's better to just increase the spacing between the PoC traces.

[image]